# Can't get Crashlytics on Android to work, getting runtime error message

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics-android

I'm having trouble getting Firebase Crashlytics to work in my Android Studio project. I keep getting these runtime errors:

```
E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings request failed.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/gmp/xxxxxxx:android:xxxxxxxxb/settings?instance=xxxxxxx8&build_version=2&display_version=2.0&source=1
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpGetRequest.execute(HttpGetRequest.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:113)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:199)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:192)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)




E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Error handling uncaught exception
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.Utils.awaitEvenIfOnMainThread(Utils.java:122)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$1.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:155)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:54)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1073)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
        at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2203)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19658 SIG: 9
```

I've tried completely removing Firebase from the project and removing the project from Firebase, in other words starting from scratch, but this isn't working either. What could be going on here?

Comment: Have you enabled crashlytics for your app?

Comment: I've done everything step-by-step from the documentation and enabled crashlytics for my app, now it has a progress bar just spinning, waiting for my crash report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by migrating my project to a new Firestore project and replacing google-services.json in my Android Studio app folder. I then invalidated cache/restart and I was able to enable Crashlytics in Firestore by forcing an app crash per documentation instruction.